# selenium.interactions.Actions class for copy/cut/paste not working in chrome browser - Selenium Test Automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have to copy a object(text/shape) in my application and paste it to another area.

In this case I have to paste irrespective to the webElement. So I can not use this -

`driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"v"));`

So I am using Actions class in selenium - `selenium.interactions.Actions`

```
actions.keyDown(command).sendKeys("c").keyUp(command).build().perform();
```

This method is not working `Chrome72` and `chromedriver 72`.

I have been facing this issue for many months. And surf the web for solutions and got many sites are speaking about that -

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5946

But couldn't find any answers and the problem still exists in very recent versions of chrome and chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a lyer in G Chrome that prevents this shortcuts:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=581

And it is NOT going to be fixed.

Maybe you could find a solution. In my case for Ctrl+T I use

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');");
```

The other option is to use a robot but it will only work in the active Window. It will not work in paralell testing. It will not work if you are working at the same time. This will send the commands to the computer, not to the browser. And your Window must be active:

```
// Create instance of Robot class
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

I hope this helps. As I said it does not work everytime ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response. For opening new tab it would work. But I need solution for copy/cut/paste. Kindly share any work arounds for this.

Comment: Updated. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks David. I will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Control+a keys in your code before copying as you might need to select entire text first then copy the text.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("xyz")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
driver.findElement(By.id("xyz")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "c"));
```